# Some apps are not able to access internet when connected to Laptop's shared wifi on Ubuntu

Tags: wi-fi, linux, ad-hoc-networks

In my office my mobile used to be connected to the office wifi. There I didn't face any internet problem, all apps work fine.

But in my home my mobile is connected to my Laptop's shared wifi and Laptop is running on Kubuntu 15.10. In this case some apps like Play Store, youtube, telegram, whatsapp and all browsers, etc. work well, but some apps do not work, sometimes partially work or otherwise show the message 'No internet connection'.

What's wrong with connection from my laptop to my mobile, and why are some apps working and some are not? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Android apps can query android for the type involved: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType%28%29

Now as a wifi connection is a wifi connection, as long as an app is enabled for wifi, the app should work otherwise the app can detect and say there's no internet connection available if the app so chooses.

There could in theory be an issue or bug with using the laptop's shared wifi but if one app queries android and gets wifi connected then they all should.

You can try an app like 'wifi fixer' and see if it helps.

I don't think its possible for anyone to give a direct answer on how to fix it other than try this and this and this, etc.

That said, as a direct wifi connection worked in the past, get a wifi router or ap and it should be fixed. This is imo what you should do.